# Can I get only the #includes from C++ files with Ctags?

Tags: c++, ctags

Is it possible to get a list of just the **#include + file** directives from a specified C++ source file with *Exuberant Ctags* or *Universal Ctags*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the latest version of Universal-ctags you can use following command line to enumerate header files:

```
$ ctags -o - --extras=r --kinds-C++=h --language-force=C++ INPUT-FILE.h
```

For examples:

```
$./ctags -o - --extras=r --kinds-C++=h --language-force=C++ /usr/include/pwd.h 

bits/types.h    /usr/include/pwd.h  /^#include <bits\/types.h>/;"   h

features.h  /usr/include/pwd.h  /^#include <features.h>/;"  h

stddef.h    /usr/include/pwd.h  /^#include <stddef.h>/;"    h

stdio.h /usr/include/pwd.h  /^# include <stdio.h>/;"    h
```

Comment: That's exactly​ what I needed. Thanks!!